# Exclude directory relative to project root

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I work in a project that has two copies of the framework it uses, one of them not being used (please don't ask):

- `C:\Projects\Foo\app\Vendor\cakephp\cakephp`
- `C:\Projects\Foo\lib\Cake`

What's the syntax to completely obliterate `\lib\Cake` in `files.exclude` or search pane?

None of these seem to work:

```
/lib/Cake
/lib/Cake/
/lib/Cake/**
lib/Cake
lib/Cake/
lib/Cake/**
**/lib/Cake
**/lib/Cake/
**/lib/Cake/**
```

… plus the same patters with Windows style path separators.

They either ignore both copies or ignore none.

Comment: FYI, I've given up. The project uses Subversion so I've checked out a sparse working copy and omitted the directory altogether.

Answer (score 0):

sample file

```
"files.exclude": {
    "*/**/node_modules/": true,
    "wp-includes/": true,
    "wp-admin/": true,
    //"wp-*.*": true,
    "wp-config.*": false,
    "xmlrpc.php": true,
    ".vscode/": true,
    "*/**/cache/": true,
    "*/**/uploads/": true,
    "*/**/infinitewp/": true,
    "*/**/.github/": true,
    //"*/**/build/": true
},
"search.exclude": {
    "build/": true,
},
```

taken from : https://daveredfern.com/hide-or-exclude-folders-and-files-from-search-in-visual-studio-code/

Comment: That sample features many different syntaxes, some of which I've already tried without success. What would be the one for the specific case of a given path from project root?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález try **/Cake

Comment: `**/Cake` excludes _both_ :(